# How often can an Imp Familiar cast Invisibility on itself?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, racial-traits

The imp's description on Roll20 suggests that an imp could turn invisible *at will* and as often as it has the time for (every turn).

> Invisibility: The imp magically turns invisible until it attacks, or until its Concentration ends (as if concentrating on a spell). Any Equipment the imp wears or carries is invisible with it.

I'm asking this because I'm allowing a warlock in my game to have an imp as familiar through the *find familiar* spell (without Pact of the Chain), but the description doesn't state anything about limitations regarding the frequency of turning invisible. Are there any?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## There is no limit to the frequency of use.

The imp's Invisibility feature is listed under Actions, and there is no indication that it has a limited number of uses. This means it can be used as often as the imp gets to take an action. The only restrictions are that it requires concentration to maintain the effect and the effect ends immediately after making an attack.

A normal familiar obtained through the *find familiar* spell can't attack anyway, so in your Warlock's scenario it's very difficult for the imp to really abuse this.

In the case of a familiar obtained by a Warlock through the Pact of the Chain feature, however, it would be able to attack. In that case, the "cost" that would limit abuse is that the Warlock would have to give up one of their own attacks to let the imp make one. This wouldn't actually limit the number of uses, but it would impose a restriction that limits its practical effectiveness.

Comment: Well, the imp could remain invisible practically all of the time, making it a valuable scout. This is definitely more powerful than existing familiars.

Comment: Just another clarifying note on the limitation: If it attacks while invisible, it will both use its action and immediately become visible. This means it will then have to wait a full round before it gets another action and can turn invisible. This makes it a lot more vulnerable than if it could truly go invisible "at will" or even as a bonus action or reaction.

Comment: jgn is of course right though, Imp as a familiar is OP as hell compared to any other option including the other Pact of the Chain options (Quasit is comparable but a direct downgrade to the Imp in most ways). This invisibility effect is key to that power, so making sure to enforce the "it takes a full action" restriction is very important!