# Can my familiar turn me invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, invisibility

If, as a multiclassed wizard/druid, I have an imp familiar from the *find familiar* spell and I wild shape into a rat, can the imp hold me and turn invisible?

Comment: How do you have an imp familiar as a wizard?

Comment: @V2Blast While this is not how OP got one, the Monster Manual has a variant Imp that can act as a familiar. Unlike the spirits summoned by the Find Familiar spell (of which only chain warlocks could summon as an Imp), these are actual devils that can form contracts with any spellcaster and act as their familiar in return for a compensation of some sort. Unlike familiars summoned by the Find Familiar spells, these familiar Imps can die, or simply leave if they consider that you have broken the terms of the contract.

Comment: @Dungarth: I'm aware of that, and that it's distinct from the *find familiar* spell, which is why I'm asking OP the question :)

Comment: Related question: [Imp familiars Invisibility affecting a PC](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82973/imp-familiars-invisibility-affecting-a-pc) Tangentially related: [How often can an Imp Familiar cast Invisibility on itself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122420/how-often-can-an-imp-familiar-cast-invisibility-on-itself)

Comment: Just to echo V2Blast's comments, your plan does not work as a wizard/druid; you would need to be a warlock/druid with the Pact of the Chain. A Pact of the Chain warlock is the _only_ way you can get an imp via the _find familiar_ spell.

Answer (score 12):

## No

The Invisibility ability the [imp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp) can use reads like this:

> ***Invisibility.*** The imp magically turns invisible until it attacks or
> until its concentration ends (as if concentrating on a spell). Any
> equipment the imp wears or carries is invisible with it.

Your character isn't equipment so the imp can't make them invisible as well. However, if you hid inside of a bag and the imp was carrying the bag it would become invisible and you'd be effectively invisible as long as you stayed inside of it.

As noted by Tiggerous, wizards by default cannot have an imp familiar. The [Find Familiar](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Find%20Familiar#content) spell states:

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that takes an animal form you choose: bat, cat, crab, frog (toad), hawk, lizard, octopus, owl, poisonous snake, fish (quipper), rat, raven, sea horse, spider, or weasel. Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form, though it is a celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice) instead of a beast.

Imps are not on that list and they are not beasts either.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that imp is a Warlock familiar, not a Wizard one.

Comment: Wizards can summon them at first level with find-familiar.

Comment: While Wizards can't use Find Familiar to summon a spirit that would take the form of an Imp, they could potentially form a contract with an actual Imp, as per the Imp entry in the Monster Manual. Given OP's comments, however, this is not how he acquired an Imp as a familiar...

Comment: @Familiarswizard211: Imp is not one of the familiar options for a wizards using the *find familiar* spell.